# Rack Middleware in Rack Middleware?

Tags: ruby, rack, middleware

I am trying to build a rack middleware **GEM** that uses rack middleware itself (RackWired).

I have an existing application, whose config.ru uses Rack::Builder. In that block (Rack::Builder), I would like to specify my middleware, and when it is called to use a third party middleware (rack-cors) inside my own to do some stuff. Confusing I know.

The problem is that Rack::Builder's context is in config.ru and my middleware (RackWired) is thus unable to access it to "use" the third party middleware (rack-cors).

The intent of my effort is [here](https://gist.github.com/daneb/48d907d9d07776a7bb85b5f734a5ccb0)

Is there a way to use middleware within middleware?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right, I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to do.  But you can do this

```
class CorsWired
  def initialize(app)
    @app = app
  end

  def call(env)
    cors = Rack::Cors.new(@app, {}) do
      allow do
        origins '*'
        resource '*', :headers => :any, :methods => [:get, :post, :put, :options, :delete], :credentials => false
      end
    end
    cors.call(env)
  end
end
```

Your config.ru should have `use CorsWired` though, not `use CorsWired.new`

This is I think what you were asking but I think you're missing the point of middleware.  You should just change your `config.ru` to use rack-cors before/after your middleware depending on what you want to do.

```
require 'rack'
require 'rack/cors'
require './cors_wired'      

app = Rack::Builder.new  do
  use Rack::Cors do
    allow do
        origins '*'
        resource '*', :headers => :any, :methods => [:get, :post, :put, :options, :delete], :credentials => false
      end
    end
  use CorsWired
  run lambda { |env| [200, {'Content-Type' => 'text/plain'}, ['OK']] }  
end
run app
```

Comment: Thanks it's the first part I was looking for. I could easily have done the latter but I am looking to add some meta-configuration for CORS hence pulling it into a Gem.

Comment: I would make a refinement with that code as you will get a syntax error without initialization of Rack::Cors.new(@app, {}) do blah blah end